# Is it possible to register the rest endpoints in MarkLogic Query console

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to register the rest endpoints in MarkLogic Query Console using XQuery?

Answer (score 2):

In Query Console, you can use the xdmp.http*() functions to call the REST API endpoints on the same server.

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "register". Are you talking about creating a new REST API extension? If so, yes, you can, using the xdmp:http-* functions, as @ehennum noted. However, taking that approach will lead to one-off solutions and I wouldn't recommend it. You'd be much better off using [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/), a tool specifically for deploying MarkLogic code and configuration.